# Can I include HTML blocks of code like footer and header on every page in Node.js whilst using ejs templating engine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

Similarly to how you can do it in PHP? For example if I have a header.ejs file that contains this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/css.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
<body>
```

Can I do something like :

```
<% include 'header.ejs' %>
```

In my home.ejs page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes use

```
<%- include('header') -%>
```

Comment: Worked out great, just one more question. If I wanted to pass data to the header ( for example if I want my title to be <% title %>, from which file am I supposed to pass the data?

Comment: you can access a variable passed from the render function and use it in the template  ```<%= title %>```

Comment: Let's say I want to display my home page view, if the title tag were in it I'd do this: 

    res.render('home', { title: 'Home'});

however, now the title tag is not in the home page view but in the header file which is included in the home view. Therefore the code above doesn't change the title.

Comment: try passing the title again to the header  ```<%- include('header' ,{ title:"your_title" }) -%>```